# Using angular 2 directive inside component template is not being rendered on a change

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

Take for example this simplae component template:

```
<div [tooltip]="text" [tooltipEnabled]="false">{{text}}</div>
```

Please notice  *tooltip* is a directive working great, but when I use it inside other component template, while I change *tooltipEnabled* to be `"true"`, I think the directive will notich the change and act, but its not.

What did I miss? It only work on first time load and any change after that will not be effacted? I can see the directive code runs, but it is reading *tooltipEnabled* proprety as `false` (the first load), while I see in html I did change it to be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be great if you could create a plunker..

Works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/zElHdyZ5jbPGx5rFtlFI?p=preview

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
  private _tooltipEnabled: boolean;

  @Input()
  set tooltipEnabled(val: boolean) {
    console.log('value changed', val);
    this._tooltipEnabled = val;

    this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = val ? '' : 'red'; // use Renderer for manipulations!!
  }

  @Input() tooltip: string;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 tooltip [tooltipEnabled]="toggleBool" (click)="toggleBool = !toggleBool">Hello {{name}} - click me</h2>
      <h2 tooltip [tooltipEnabled]="false">Should be red..</h2>
      <h2 tooltip [tooltipEnabled]="true">Should be white..</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  public toggleBool = true;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! I understand from your example I MUST use "toogleBool" object for that to work. Setting it directle to true/false in html and it won't work

Comment: no, there's not need for this variable.. was just for showing a toggled value. :)

Comment: see my updated answer and plunker, works fine with constant values.

Comment: Try to change the true to false by code, that didn't work for me. At first load it works, but when chaging the true to false with setAttribute('tooltipEnabled', true) that not worked

Comment: Ah I see, if you do it like this you are bypassing Angular and it will not detect that changes.. You are correct. Better use the Angular-ways! :)